# In Jersey, how to return an object with 400 response code different than the 200 response object

Tags: rest, web-services, jersey, client

I am new to Jersey and to REST in general, so this might be a stupid question....

In my code, I send a request (`TemplateValidationRequest`) to try to validate an object. If the object fails to validate, I want to return a String. How do I do this?

In the second code snippet at the bottom, you can see that I'm looking for  `TemplateValidationResponse` object. How can I change my code so that:

1. I can return a string, and
2. I can get a String instead of a `TemplateValidationResponse` object.

Is this possible?

```
@POST
@Path("validate/modelTemplate")
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
@Operation(
    summary = "Convert model template to AMBOS interaction model and validate the result",
    tags = { BLUEPRINTS_TAG },
    requestBody = @RequestBody(
        content = @Content(
            schema = @Schema(
                implementation = TemplateValidationRequest.class
            )
        )
    ),
    responses = {
        @ApiResponse(
            responseCode = "200",
            description = "Success.",
            content = @Content(
                schema = @Schema(
                    implementation = TemplateValidationResponse.class
                )
            )
        ),
        @ApiResponse(
            responseCode = "400",
            description = "Failure",
            content = @Content(
                schema = @Schema(
                    implementation = String.class
                )
            )
        )
    }
)
@CustomerIdentityRequired
@AcceptsLanguageRequired
@AAA(serviceName = SERVICE_NAME, operationName = BLUEPRINTS_GET)
ModelTemplateValidationResponse validateModelTemplate(TemplateValidationRequest);
```

```
fun validateModelTemplate(modelTemplate: InteractionModel,
                          sampleData: Map<String, Any>): TemplateValidationResponse {
  val request = TemplateValidationRequest()
  request.modelTemplate = modelTemplate
  request.sampleData = sampleData
  return temp.validateModelTemplate(request)//this is where I call the above code
    //If this request fails and results in a 400 error, I want to get a String
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about something like:

```
public Class YourResponse {
    private boolean isError;
    private String setThisWhenThereIsError;
    private YourObject setThisWhen200;
}
```